# A boy is selected at random from among the children belonging to families with n children.

Tags: probability

A boy is selected at random from among the children belonging to families with n children.

---

Question 1：What is the probability that the boy has k − 1 brothers?

The answer I got is (n-1)!/(2 ^(n-1)*(k-1)!*(n-k)!)

---

Question 2：If the boy has at least two sisters， what is the probability that the boy has k − 1 brothers now?

Comment: What work have you already attempted on this problem?

Comment: I got the answer for the question 1, but I don' know the answer for question 2.

Comment: For question 1, I got (n-1)!/(2 ^(n-1)*(k-1)!*(n-k)!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that children are born equally likely to be boys as girls.

**Question 1.**  All $2^n$ possible sequences of boys and girls are equally likely.  If we were to write out all such sequences, there would be $n2^n$ children, and $n2^{n-1}$ of them would be boys.  Any of them could be selected, with equal probability, for the purposes of this problem.

There would be, on the other hand, $\binom{n}{k}$ sequences with $k$ boys in that list, and thus $k\binom{n}{k}$ boys who could each say that they have $k-1$ brothers.  The probability we desire is therefore the ratio of these two quantities:

$$
\frac{k\binom{n}{k}}{n2^{n-1}}
$$

The answer you got, which can be written

$$
\frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{2^{n-1}}
$$

is the probability that a randomly selected *child* can say that they have $k-1$ brothers.  But we didn't randomly select a child; we randomly selected a boy.  So the probabilities are different.

**Question 2.** We assume first that $n \geq k+2$.  The number of sequences with $k$ boys remains the same, then; all that need be adjusted is the denominator, which represents the possible range of boys.  From the total number of boys must be subtracted all boys in sequences with no girls at all, and all boys in sequences with exactly one girl.  There are $n\binom{n}{n} = n$ and $(n-1)\binom{n}{n-1} = n^2-n$ of those respectively, so the number of boys available for selection is now $n2^{n-1}-n^2$, and the new probability is

$$
\frac{k\binom{n}{k}}{n2^{n-1}-n^2}
$$

If $n < k+2$, the probability is $0$, as there are not enough children left to be boys, after the girls are accounted for.